# ng-animate in AngularJS validation

Tags: javascript, html, forms, angularjs

I'm trying to integrate the shake effect in an AngularJS validation but I am failing to do so using animate.css. Here is my code:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" 
            ng-model="firstName" 
            ng-class="{'animate shake':submitted && myForm.firstName.$invalid }" 
            class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" value="" required/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" 
            ng-model="lastName" 
            ng-class="{'animate shake':submitted && myForm.lastName.$invalid }" 
            class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" required />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" name="input" id="emailId" 
            ng-model="email" 
            ng-class="{'animate shake':submitted && myForm.input.$invalid }" 
            class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required />
</div>
<button class="button primary" id="submit_form" type="submit" 
            ng-click="submitted = true">Submit</button>
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you actually used `ng-animate` - am I missing something?

Comment: I have used animation through css so I have added animate and shake class if validation fails in ng-class

Comment: Ok then you aren't using ng-animate, and this is a general question about css3 animation. Please update your title to reflect that.

Comment: Earlier I was using ng-animate but it did not work out so tried this, is this possible with ng-animate if validation fails it shake??

Comment: All `ng-animate` AND `ng-class` do is add/remove classes according to certain actions. In this case you are correctly adding two classes (`animate` and `shake`) if `submitted` is truthy and `myForm.firstName.$invalid` is truthy. It is up to YOU to actually control the animations via CSS. If you can confirm that the class is being added, then the issue is in your css.

Comment: shake effect is working when I am doing single validation but when I am checking for more than one like (required,email = true) then its failing...

Comment: Again, all angular does is add those two classes. Are the classes being added when the form is invalid? Are you sure you're setting `submitted` to a truthy value? Are you sure the form is being set to invalid when you expect the shake effect to happen?

Comment: yes its adding correct the class on ng-invalid but they are not removing on ng-valid when you move to next one...

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by "move to next one". Please update your question with all of the relevant information, whether the classes are being added, whether you are able to identify this as a CSS or Javascript issue, etc.

Comment: Move to next one means moving to another input field... I am updating the question. .

Comment: Well wouldn't moving to another input field not cause `submitted` to be truthy? Unless you mislabeled your scope variables